# Calling a service inside thread

Tags: android, multithreading, maps

I'm developing and Android app that uses the GMaps API. I also have a PSQL database on a server, that calculates geographic information, like routes etc..

After the user clicks on the "GO" Button, I want to contact my server with the coordinates of the user's address to get the route path from my database. I'm running those proccesses under a Thread, inside of the "onResume()" and I don't want to perform an AsyncTask, because I want that the user waits until the route gets received from the server. How can I achieve that?

**OnResume()**

```
//** Prevents map = null*/
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(mapFrag.getMap().equals(null)){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    configMap();
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
}
```

**configMap()**

```
public void configMap(){

route=null;
resultAddress = new ArrayList<Address>();
routeList=new ArrayList<LatLng>();

//Go button
goButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);

//From and target address
fromAddress= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fromAddress);
toAddress= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toAddress);

//Opens and defines the map
map=mapFrag.getMap();
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

LatLng mapPoint;

mapPoint=new LatLng(38.741284, -9.146643);

//Displays the map on the previous map coordinates
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(mapPoint).zoom(14).build();
CameraUpdate update=CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

//Set the marker to current position
MarkerOptions currentOptions =new MarkerOptions();
currentOptions.draggable(false);
currentOptions.title("My Location");
currentOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
currentOptions.position(mapPoint);

//Displays the marker
currentPosition=map.addMarker(currentOptions);
```

**OnClick()**

```
        //Gets the coordinates for the source and target of the route
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    Geocoder fromcoder = new Geocoder(Map.this);
                    LatLng fromLatlng = null;
                    List<Address> fromAddresses= new ArrayList<Address>();

                    Geocoder Tocoder = new Geocoder(Map.this);
                    LatLng toLatlng = null;
                    List<Address> toAddresses= new ArrayList<Address>();

                    //Saves coordinates of from address
                    try {
                        fromAddresses=getLocation(fromAddress.getText().toString() , fromAddresses);

                        //Saves coordinates of to address
                        toAddresses = getLocation((String) toAddress.getText().toString() , toAddresses);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                            //Removes previous From marker
                            if(markerFrom!=null) markerFrom.remove();
                            //Removes previous To marker
                            if(markerTo!=null) markerTo.remove();

                    /**
                    *   Here I want to CONNECT and Get the route to print on the map
                    *   (Preference to call another class, because I don't want to put all code
                    *    in here)
                    */


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to perform an AsyncTask, because I want that the user waits until the route gets received from the server

You can achieve this using AsynTask. Show `progressBar` in `preExecute()` and do whatever server interaction in `doInBackground()`

Comment: Humm.. But if I have some code after calling that asyncTask, will it be executed just after the task?

Comment: Humm... let me try ;)